Upgrading AWS RDS aurora from serverless v1 to serverless v2 using terraform
I'm upgrading AWS rds aurora postgress cluster from serverless v1 to serverless v2 using terraform.
The steps that I followed:

Creating snapshot of the serverless v1 cluster
Creating provisioned db cluster from that snapshot
Creating instance for provisioned db
Creating snapshot of provisioned db cluster
Finally creating the serverless v2 from the provisioned snapshot

Below is my terraform config for serverless v2:
 resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_rds_serverless_v2" {
   cluster_identifier = "aurora-v2-serverless-cluster-new-197789"
   engine = local.env_config.rds_engine
   engine_version = local.env_config.rds_engine_version
   backup_retention_period = 14
   engine_mode = "serverless"
   snapshot_identifier= aws_db_cluster_snapshot.aurora_rds_provisioned_db_snapshot.id
   apply_immediately = true
   skip_final_snapshot = true
   enable_http_endpoint         = true
   timeouts {
     create = "120m"
   }
   scaling_configuration {
     auto_pause = true
     min_capacity = 2
     max_capacity = 4
   }
 }

My question is do I need to create separate terraform resource to define instance for serverless v2 or does it auto scale?
Something like this:
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_serverless_instance" {
  count = 2 # Example: Two instances (one writer, one reader)
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.aurora_rds_provisioned_db_v2.id
  instance_class = "db.r5.large"
  apply_immediately = true
}


Aurora Serverless v2 does not auto-scale the number of instances. The capacity of the serverless instance itself is auto-scaled. Serverless v2 uses cluster mode "provisioned" not "serverless", then you configure individual instances in the cluster to be either provisioned, or serverless instances, via the instance_class attribute. There's a complete example of this on the rds_cluster resource documentation page, here.
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "example" {
  cluster_identifier = "example"
  engine             = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_mode        = "provisioned"
  engine_version     = "13.6"
  database_name      = "test"
  master_username    = "test"
  master_password    = "must_be_eight_characters"
  storage_encrypted  = true

  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = 1.0
    min_capacity = 0.5
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "example" {
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.example.id
  instance_class     = "db.serverless"
  engine             = aws_rds_cluster.example.engine
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.example.engine_version
}


thanks for the info. I have another question -> Do we need to create an intermediate provisioned cluster while going from v1 to v2? Or we can do it directly?

Is this how it should be? ->


Create a snapshot of the Serverless v1 cluster.


Create a provisioned cluster from the Serverless v1 snapshot.


Create db.serverless instances for that provisioned cluster.



I don't think you can update an instance's class from provisioned to serverless. I think that actually requires replacement of the instance. Obviously Terraform handles that for you. I do seem to remember needing to add a provisioned instance at first, because of the DB version upgrade you need to do, before you can get to a version of postgres that is supported by Serverless v2. After that DB upgrade version is complete, then you would switch to a serverless instance.

Currently I'm using postgress 13 which supports v2. Do I still need to create provisioned instance or I can directly go with db.serverless?

I suggest you try it out and let us know.

sure will do that. One more thing would be how can I delete the old cluster? I do recall there's some null_reference resource in terraform. Do you know about this?

Just remove the old cluster from your terraform code, and run terraform apply again, and Terraform will delete any resources that exist in the Terraform state, but no longer exist in your Terraform template. Although Terraform isn't as good at handling dependencies on deletes, and you sometimes have to just go into the AWS console to do the delete, and then run terraform apply to get the state refreshed.

that's the problem, I can't do any manual update in AWS. It has to be through terraform and also I'm not allowed to manually remove the code. Can it be done through any TF resource?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't know what you mean by "manually remove the code". If you have two aws_rds_cluster resources defined now, one for the V1 cluster, and one for the V2, you will absolutely have to remove the V1 cluster definition when you are ready to delete the V1 server. If you don't delete that Terraform code, then the next time you run Terraform it will re-create the V1 server again.

Makes sense, got it. Thanks Mark

About deleting the old cluster, I'm kind of confused because I'm using old cluster's id to create snapshot and then using the snapshot to create the serverless v2 cluster. If I remove the old cluster's code, my flow would break right? does this work? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource

You do not need a null resource here. You absolutely have to delete the old cluster's code. Otherwise Terraform will start recreating the old cluster every time you run it. You should be able to reference that snapshot without referencing the old cluster. Hard code the snapshot ID if you have to.

Got it, basically after first TF apply I can remove the old code, modify the snapshot resource to remove the old cluster reference and hard code the snapshot id in the new cluster. Right? Instead of hard coding snapshot id should I add a lifecycle block ignoring snapshot_id so that it ignores the snapshot after first TF apply?

That sounds correct. I don't think Terraform even cares about the snapshot ID after the DB has been created. I think you could just delete the snapshot ID attribute from the resource after the DB is up, but obviously running terraform plan to confirm that is best.

I got a suggestion to use the existing cluster and instance to perform the v2 upgrade. How can this be done? Can you please help me on this

@Coding_ninja I'm not sure that's possible. You would have to add a non-serverless instance to the cluster in order to perform the upgrade, and I'm not sure serverless v1 allows that.

Understood. The problem is deleting the old cluster code after the upgrade. This needs to be done in 2 deployments. I need to figure out a way to make this happen in single go. Is that even doable?

It is not doable in a single go at all. You absolutely need to do this in multiple steps.
